# Netstat in Fedora doesn't list simple netcat server, Ubuntu does

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, netcat, netstat

I'm opening a simple TCP server with `netcat`:

```
$ netcat -l -p 1234
```

Then I want to check if it's listed among the listening tcp connections by `netstat`:

```
$ netstat -lt
```

If I issue the previous commands on an Ubuntu system

```
$ uname -v
#65~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 19 18:57:09 UTC 2016
```

my server is correctly listed:

```
$ netstat -lt
...
tcp        0      0 *:1234                  *:*                     LISTEN
...
```

If I do the very same thing on a Fedora system:

```
$ uname -r
3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64
```

in this case I can't find my server:

```
$ netstat -lt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:search-agent    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:search-agent       [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

This problem also happens when I write a program opening a server socket, and I need to write a test to automatically check if the server is listening on the correct port (works on Ubuntu, not on Fedora). Is it possible to make this kind of check on Fedora using `netstat` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu probably has different default switches for netstat than fedora , so you are seeing "symbolic" names for ports instead of port numbers. Add switch -n to fedora netstat (IIRC) to use numeric ports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if any other service - port mapping exists for port number `1234`, in `/etc/services` configuration file.

Example.

On `OEL 6`, I see port 1234 is mapped to service called `search-agent`. Now below outputs are self explanatory

```
# netstat -l | grep -i search-agent
#
#  nc -l 1234
```

On Other terminal

```
#netstat -l | grep -i search-agent
tcp        0      0 *:search-agent              *:*                         LISTEN
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can actually see `search-agent` entries in my `/etc/services` file, but the service is not running. Anyway this will be very useful when I'll have to choose which port to use for my servers.